# Optimized for iPhone 6 info text in App Store

Tags: xcode5, app-store, ios8

I've updated my "old" Objective-C app to use the new storyboard with size classes, set the deployment target to iOS 8 and uploaded the new binary to the App Store. Still, the App Store doesn't show the text "this app is optimized for iPhone 6 and 6 plus". The text only mentions iPhone 5S and everything below.

What am I supposed to do in order to get the app iPhone 6 approved?

Comment: have you included the new app icon for iPhone6? (`...@3x.png`)

Comment: Yes I have, all fields in the "app icon" assets catalogue are filled with icons, including the @3x ones.

Comment: Maybe every image, not only the app icons, have to exist in a `@3x` version?

Comment: yes, that is the case. you need to present the images for `@3x` scale for iPhone6/6+.

Comment: So could this be the crucial point which currently prevents the wanted App Store text from appearing?

Comment: that may be possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution was to add `@3x` versions for all used images and using the new size classes. You notice the app from switching to iPhone 6 supported when e.g. table cells look different (get very small) to adjust to the new screen size.

**Update for clarity:**

Before iPhone 6 and 6 Plus, my images were named like this:

```
Icon-40.png
Icon-40@2x.png
```

In order to get the wanted `optimized for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus` text, you need to add a third resolution of each image and name them with a `@3x` where the `@2x` was before. So you end up having these three images -**per image** you want to show in the app-.

```
Icon-40.png
Icon-40@2x.png
Icon-40@3x.png
```

Comment: hi linus, can you explain what you mean by renaming all used images?...do you mean we have to rename all our images we used in our app (background, buttons, etc.) to @3x? If so, what is the naming convention?

Comment: You could have just added a launch screen instead of all the fuss. Just saying.

Comment: This answer is in fact incorrect. It's all about the launch screens, just like MichalShatz notes.

Answer (score 2):

> IMPORTANT
>
> You use a launch XIB or storyboard file to indicate that your app runs
>   on iPhone 6 Plus or iPhone 6.

From [Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html)

Comment: If you only set this "flag", I suppose you get the wanted text but end up having blurred images in the app.

Comment: @Linus, on the opposite side if you are using launch image of right size(not launch xib or storyboard), @ 3x images and not using autolayout on your xibs (resizing in code), you will get good looking app on iphone6, but in app store there will be no text, that app is optimized for iPhone6(+). Adding autolayout on xibs solves this issue.

Comment: I just realized one of my apps that I certainly have NOT added iPhone 6/iPhone 6 Plus launch images for does still indeed display as optimized for iPhone 5, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus. (!!) This must be an error by Apple...