# iTunes shows my app as iPhone 5 optimized while it's running at native resolution on an iPhone 6/6+

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

I've submitted my app with iPhone 6 and 6+ launch screens and screen shots. I've checked the app in the simulator and it does show the right proportions (not just scaled) of the app for iPhone 6 and 6+. Yet in iTunes they call the app optimised for iPhone 5:

[image]

I've asked iPhone 6 users to check and indeed it works right. But I would like my app to be in the "optimised for iPhone 6 section" because a lot of people are looking for apps that run natively on their new phones.

Here's the app: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ovo-timer/id925582403?ls=1&mt=8

---

I have been trying to find more info. The only thing I found was this:
http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/05/02/how-to-indicate-what-devices-are-supported-by-your-ios-app
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013599-CH17-SW1

My app only requires ARMv7 in the Info.plist file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This app has all it's graphics drawn with vectors except one small icon in the app that I show when you wind. If this is the culprit then upgrading that icon would solve the problem.

Found here:
[Optimized for iPhone 6 info text in App Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210622/optimized-for-iphone-6-info-text-in-app-store)