# Xcode 6 resizes app automatically for iPhone 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, xcode6

I was developing app in Xcode 5 for iOS 7 on iPhone 5 inch storyboard. I prepared my app and its buttons, images and other stuff to fit iPhone 5 screen size, and then programmatically optimized app to fit iPhone 4 and 4s.

And then Xcode 6 came, and two new devices, iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus. I was thinking that i will have to spend few hours again to programmatically optimize app for those resolutions.

But i tried run my app on my new iPhone 6 and strange thing happened. App itself made everything for me. Everything was in right position and right size and i haven't done anything.

I saw that Xcode 6 now uses Size Classes to develop app for multiple devices.

But i am not using Size Classes and Auto Layout in my project and it works?

I opened new project then. In my new project resizing is not working like this anymore. So it won't resize my buttons, views and other stuff automatically.

Has anyone have any idea what is happening?

Comment: The system will automatically scale you application up to fit the new screen sizes if you haven't prepared the correct assets in the new sizes. So your app will work but not at the size of a native 6/6+ application.

Comment: @jshier so its better for me to work with Size Classes? And what will happened if I am developing a game in Sprite Kit? Systems will automatically change sizes of sprites?

Comment: Using sizes classes isn't required for iOS to stop zooming your app. You just need a launch image of the appropriate resolution.

Comment: @jshier maybe its strange question. Where in options i have to chose, that my app will zoom my objects in on different resolutions? Like my old project does?

Comment: You don't. It's done automatically at runtime depending on whether your launch image was the correct resolutions for the new screens.

Comment: @jshier i thought so.. but its not working for me... i set all launch images and tried working on iPhone 5 storyboard, on my iPhone 6 device it is still presenting app as it would run on iPhone 5.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you don't use a launch story board or include launch images for the new iPhone 6 sizes, the entire screen will expand to fill the new device size (same thing happens when enabling Zoom in accessibility settings). The iPhone 6 user will notice larger fonts, images, etc.

This is what's happening. The problem is that you don't get to take advantage of extra screen real estate (extra pixels). If that's cool with you, then keep it, but when you do finally optimize your app to use that extra real-estate the iPhone 6 users will suddenly complain that the font size has gotten smaller when it stops auto-zooming.

You should spend the time to optimize it for iPhone 6 and include launch images (or launch story board if supporting iOS 8+ only), and get the "Optimized for iPhone 6" note added to your app description.

Comment: now I understand... So it works just in case that you add lauch images... But for me it's better to zoom  as I am developing games at it looks really cool on bigger devices..

Comment: hi Marcus, I have launched a launch xib for proper scaling for the iPhone 6/6+, but upon reading another thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210622/optimized-for-iphone-6-info-text-in-app-store, the person is talking about @3x, and I'm confused on that. Can you elaborate on what the person is talking about? Thanks

Comment: The 3x images have nothing to do with getting the *This app is optimized for iPhone 5, iPhone 6, and iPhone 6 Plus.* text. Here's one of my apps. No images above 2x, but I have every required launch image, and it [says it's optimized](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sound-it-out-spelling/id916263370?mt=8). If you understand 2x scaled images for retina devices, iPhone 6 Plus retina has an even higher scale of 3x. Set any image views on your launch storyboard to automatically scale or include all scale sizes so they're the right size.

Comment: Hi Marcus, I have a legacy code which uses auto resizing and is built for iPhone 5 and it scales for iPhone 6 and 6 Plus but it doesn't zoom for iPhone X. Could you please tell me if there is a way that scaling can be done on iPhone X or is it not possible to zoom the app for iPhone X.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue and bring back the auto zoom for the applications, just do not set the Lauch screen file and put an image named Default-568h@2x.png (640x1136 pixels) in your project.
Now make the entire project using iPhone SE screen size in the storyboard. When the application opens on the larger screen iphones, the view image will fill the entire screen.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't touch your app pre iOS 8, it will automatically work in iPhone 6 and 6 Plus devices.  But if you want to use size classes (as you should), then you'll have to add the autolayout constraints to make things all good.

Comment: What happens in ios9?
My iphone5 app works fine on a iPhone 6 if it is in zoomed mode.  In standard mode it gets "squished" to the top right.