# Keyboard size issue in ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios6, xcode6

Keyboard size issue in ios sdk.
My problem is I create non arc xib project but this project keyboard is second image keyboard.
And i want to my project same as this first images keyboard.

[image]

Comment: textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardDoneButtonView; have you used this code in your project ?

Comment: hi sir you miss understand my question...

Comment: You don’t have the properly launch images for iPh6 or iPh6+ and your app it’s in “zoomed” mode

Comment: i have already insert launch image but not solve this problem

Comment: but how to add launch image in xcode6.

Comment: Asset Catalogs @MaulikSalvi https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27410204/1702413