# Can I create a auto scale up app using Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7

Originally I was used Xcode 5 (w/ iphone5) to create an app, and it worked good on Xcode 6 w/ iOS7/8, even on iPhone 6 and 6+, the app will automatically scale up to fit the new screen sizes. Recently I have migrated to Xcode 7 and found there is a black bars on top and bottom, so I follow the suggestions to include main.storyboard as launch screen file, but now the app will not be able to scale it up automatically. I found a discussion about this: [Xcode 6 resizes app automatically for iPhone 6 and 6 plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27409666/xcode-6-resizes-app-automatically-for-iphone-6-and-6-plus)

So I try to create an single view app from scratch (using Xcode 7), delete the Launch Screen File and Launch Image Sources, put something objects on the view, and then remove Auto Layout and Size Classes from main.storyboard, but the app does not expand to fill the new device size for 6+.

Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way is **Use xcassets**, you need to  Create a **Launch Image Set** and add all images with proper size

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your comments. Now it works if I remove the Launch Screen File, and then assign only one Launch Images Source. But I'm not sure what is the relationship between the settings and UIs, and if so I can't use xib fie to generate the splash screen dynamically...

Comment: You can also use Launch.xib. no issues

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an assets file. File->Create->Resource->Assets Catalog
2. Select the file, and add New iOS Launch Image
3. Add an image for each size. **Make sure that the resolution of the file has the same aspect ratio as the required file, but the resolution that you want your app to have. E.g. even though it expects 1242 x 2208 for iPhone 5.5, enter 640x1136, and your app will be scaled down to 320x568 with retina autoscaling**
4. You can find out the expected resolution to determine the aspect ratio in the properties inspector at the bottom of the right tab.
5. Finally, go to your target's configuration under General->App Icons and Launch Images and set your launch image source to LaunchImage (or whatever you called the image).