# Minimum splash screen required for upload App from Xcode 8.2

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode8, splash-screen

I'm working on a very old project, previously it was developed in old version of Xcode (7.3).
Now I want to make it compatible to Xcode 8.2 with minimum changes.

There is no splash screen for iOS 8 or later.
When I add this all the screen will be change, I don't want to do that changes in UI.

Can any one knows that can we able to upload app without splash screen of iOS 8 and later like (iPhone 6, 6Plus...)
Can Apple allow that?

I have tried some goggling but can't find any way.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Just upload it, and it will be resized according to the screen size if you don't provide splash screen for iOS 8 or later. I'm assuming you're supporting the iPhone 4 and iPhone 5. Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/27409666/468724